# Is there a way to open my application on a specific tab upon receiving a push notification?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is there a way to open my application on a specific tab upon receiving a push notification?

Answer (score 1):

Do a search for Push Notification tutorial on Google, you'll find a few really good links.
Study the examples and review the code.

Then create a method something like this:

-(void)goToNewsTab
{
[controller setSelectedIndex:4];
}

Where controller is your UITabBar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

Try setting the selectedIndex property of your UITabBarController.

Comment: Have an example for this? :) What I want to do is for example: You have a new news message -> open -> application opens in news tab.

Comment: If you post what you have, I'll try and see why it's not working.