# go to home screen of the iphone app after coming from background

Tags: iphone, background, push-notification

I am trying to find out how should i take the user to the home screen of my app, after he comes back from the background.

I don't want to take the user to the home screen all the time when he is coming from the background.

But only when he clicks "view" on my push notification alert and the app was in the background at that time, i want to take him to the home screen.

But if he is opening the app from the background in general he should go where ever he was left off last time he clicked on the home button and went to background

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Yogesh

Comment: I've not worked with push notifications, but I can tell that you that your app should open wherever it was after hitting the home button and then resuming - it's part of the multitasking nature of iOS 4. As for opening on a specific part after having received a notification, check the linked thread and search around a little more. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968372/is-there-a-way-to-open-my-application-on-a-specific-tab-upon-receiving-a-push-not

Comment: Hi Krypton, yes I know that I can user to a given tab but the problem that I am having is as all my tabs are navigation stack the tabs are buried deep into the stack, i need to bring it to root and then push it into again to a given view, and that's what I a finding it difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i am not sure if this right way of doing it or not, but this is what i did, as my application have a tabbarcontroller the first thing that i did is i implemented the delegate method of the tabbarcontroller "didSelectViewController"

// By doing this every time you select a tab it will come back to the rootViewController of that tab

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{

     if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]){
         [(UINavigationController *)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
     }

}
```

and then on didReceiveRemoteNotification

```
if(tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1){
    UINavigationController *navigationController  = (UINavigationController*)tabBarController.selectedViewController;
    [navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [[[navigationController viewControllers ] objectAtIndex:0]viewWillAppear:YES];
}else{
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

so let me explain what this is doing, it is checking if the current tab is 1 if it is then it will remove all the view from the navigation stack to bring the view to the root view, if the current tab is not 1 and just make it to 1.

Answer (score 0):

There one bool property in info.plist--Application does not run in background

you should change that according to your requirement.

Comment: iAmitWagh, Ya there is a property but that is to enable or disable the background thing, i want to run my application on background because I am doing some stuff on the background